# Database design for editable table

Tags: sql, database-design

I have to design an application which will store products with default values, in  a table called `default_products` .
This application will be used by customers (or users) who should be able to use the products from the `default_products` table, with their default value, but they should also be able to :

> 1. edit and customize the default values of such product records for
>    their own personal use - without affecting the product records of
>    the other customers.
> 2. add their own products, but these products should not be visible to other users.

One solution I could imagine would be:

> - one `default_products` table containing all the default products with their default values
> - one `custom_products` table with all the products crated by the users, and also a copy of the default product the user would have customized,
>   and a boolean field like `is_update` to indicate if it is an update
>   from a default_product record
> - A function which looks first for the updated product records from the `custom_product` table, then queries the `default_products` table and
>   returns records from the `default_product` table + only the updated and
>   custom products for that user from the `custom_product` table.

Example:

```
default_product
 - id
 - name
 - price

custom_product
 - default_product.ID
 - custom_price
```

I want the query to return: `default_product.ID, default_product.name, custom_product.price` **only if there is a record in custom_product corresponding to the product in default_prduct**, otherwise return: `default_product.ID, default_product.name, default_product.price`.

Any idea if this is any good? Or does anybody have any easier way to do?

Comment: IMO, a `user` table and a `product` table with `user_id` ref `user` and a `product_name` or `product_id`, and store default value into `product` whenever there is a new `user` entry, and update whenever a user update his/her product list.

Comment: I don't think there is a need to seperate `default` and `custom` into two table, as well as boolean to indicate update status.

Comment: @Thomas Ballandras you can use the `JOIN` query with `WHEN CASE` as you data needed

Comment: Better asked at sister site, DBA.StackExchange.com

Comment: Let's say a product has a default price of 19.95. A user selects that product and *does not* customize the price. Later, the default price is changed to 29.95. What is the price of the user's product? 19.95 or 29.95? In other words, do they get a copy or an alias?

Answer (score 1):

How you approach this depends on whether the user has a *copy* of the default, or an *alias* to the default. That is, once a user has selected a product, do they see updates to the name and price of the default?

---

If it's an alias, you could have a products table to store products, and a user_products table to store which products the user has selected and any customization.

```
products:
  id
  name not null
  price not null

user_products:
  id
  user_id not null
  product_id
  name
  price
```

user_products.name and user_products.price are allowed to be null. If null, they will use the value from products. You do this using [`coalesce`](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp) which will pick the first non-null value.

If a user wants to add their own product, user_products.product_id is null. Do a `left join` to ensure a result.

```
select
  coalesce(up.name, p.name) as name,
  coalesce(up.price, p.price) as price
from user_products up
left join products p on p.id = up.product_id
where user_id = ?
```

The disadvantage is the two tables have to be maintained in sync, and queries have to be written to coalesce each field. This might be a use case for table inheritance, if your database supports it.

---

If it's a copy, have a single table with a user_id column which can be null.

```
products:
  id
  user_id
  name not null
  price not null
```

When `products.user_id` is null these are the defaults available to anyone.

When a user selects a product, its values are copied to a new row with that user_id. Once a product is selected by a user they do not see future changes to the default. This may or may not be desirable.

You can optionally include an original_product_id column to remember which default product the user copied from.

The advantage is only one table needs to be maintained and the queries are simple.